# Restsharp how to specify ContentType for a parameter in a MultiPart/form-data Request

Tags: c#, multipartform-data, restsharp

I'm trying to send a document to a REST service using RestSharp.
The request must be a multipart/form-data request with two parameters.
The first one, with the name "request" must have content-type/application-JSON.

I'm using the code below
but I don't understand how to force this content-type only for this parameter.
If I go throw the debug session the value of para.content-type is always "null".

```
var request = new RestRequest("/sendDocument")
{
   AlwaysMultipartFormData = true
};
var param = Parameter.CreateParameter("request", sendDocRequestObjectRequest, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
request.AddParameter("request", param, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
request.AddFile("files", @"c:\test.pdf");
var response = restClient.Post(request);
```

Using Postman, I can specify the content-type "multipart/form-data" for the Header and "application-JSON" only for the parameter. In this case, everything is working fine.
How can I have the same behaviour as Postman using Restsharp?

Answer (score 0):

RestSharp will automatically use the multipart form content type when you add a file.

If your request doesn't contain files, and you still want to post using a multipart form, you can set `request.AlwaysMultipartFormData` property to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that your RestSharp multipart/form-data request handles a specific parameter as "application/json" content type, a minor adjustment is required in your code.

```
var request = new RestRequest("/sendDocument")
{
   AlwaysMultipartFormData = true
};

var requestJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(sendDocRequestObjectRequest);

request.AddParameter(new BodyParameter("request", requestJson, "application/json"));

request.AddFile("files", @"c:\test.pdf");
var response = restClient.Post(request);
```

In this case RestSharp will add `request` parameter with `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`.